# sugarcrm 6.5 set number columns to 3 in one tab/panel, 2 in other tabs

Tags: sugarcrm, detailview

I know how to set the columns in a detailview to 3 columns instead of the default 2 by putting into detailviewdefs.php

(in modules/EvMgr_Pgm/metadata if creating a custom module

or in custom/modules/EvMgr_Pgm/metadata if editing an existing module)

```
'maxColumns' => '3',
'widths' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => '8',
    'field' => '19',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => '8',
    'field' => '19',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => '8',
    'field' => '19',
  ),
),
```

However, that sets the columns for ALL the tabs/panels in a detailview

Is there a way I can have there be 3 columns in one tab/panel and 2 columns (default) in the other tabs/panels?

Comment: Not without re-factoring or extending how Edit and Detail views are presented. Never done this for this reason, but I have extended EditView before and it's very tedious. Has to have it's own action_view_map entry, view definition, editviewdefs, etc. "Gotchas" I've seen all have to do with how the forms reference itself, everything wants to say "editview" when really it's "mycustomeditview" -- Good luck.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  And in this case, since I want to be able to do it in Accounts, when I install another package, all the changes would have to be done via manifest scripting, which adds to its complexity.  I was hoping there was something like the ParserFactory you showed me for editviewdefs.php, but apparently not.  Worth a try ...

Comment: Oh yeah, no way you'd be able to reliably package something like this for mass-distribution without wiping out a system's existing field layouts. Well, maybe for a single custom module... so it depends on if you want multiple modules to use this 3/2 switchup layout or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the widths to exceed 100 it'll recalculate the widths for a panel/table that has 3 or more columns. Try this:

```
'maxColumns' => '3',
'widths' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => '10',
    'field' => '30',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => '10',
    'field' => '30',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => '10',
    'field' => '30',
  ),
),
```

This uses the standard 2 column 10/30 width. When a panel is created with 3 columns it'll recalculate the widths since it is greater than 100. At least as of 6.5.18 it does. Most likely it does for previous versions as well.

Comment: NOTE: This works great on the edit view. Detail view chokes still. It works, but isn't the prettiest. Alternative is to have a separate smarty template, render it in a custom view, then load it into a single field that is in the panel.